# How NoSQL database store data on the server?

Tags: xml, database, file, nosql

This might be a noobie question - How NoSQL databases stores the data on the servers?

What I really mean by that is: Is the data being stored on the server as a file? Like when we create a simple .txt file with some raw text on it, but in this case a .json or .xml file?

I really can't find/understand how actually a database stores the data on the server/computer. Firebase Firestore as example... how their file management would actually look like?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm just wondering what the purpose of your question is  - why do you care how   a database stores its data?

Comment: There are many different NOSQL databases.  Look in the documentation for whichever one you are using.

Comment: Each engine has it's own strategy and organization to store data. In the end all databases use files and folders in the file system (unless it's an in memory db or cache, of course).